# How to count exact matches across two data frames within IDs in R

Tags: r, count, aggregate, matching, exact-match

I have two datasets similar to the one below (but with 4m observations) and I want to count the number of matching sample days between the two data frames (see example below).

```
DF1                   
ID   date             
1    1992-10-15       
1    2010-02-17
2    2019-09-17
2    2015-08-18
3    2020-10-27
3    2020-12-23

DF2 
ID   date
1    1992-10-15
1    2001-04-25
1    2010-02-17
3    1990-06-22
3    2014-08-18
3    2020-10-27

Expected output 
ID   Count
1    2
2    0
3    1
```

I have tried the aggregate function (though unsure what to put in "which":

```
test <- aggregate(date~ID, rbind(DF1, DF2), length(which(exact?)))
```

and the table function:

```
Y<-table(DF1$ID)
    X <- table(DF2$ID)
    Y2 <- DF1[Y %in% X,]
```

I am having trouble finding an example to help my situation.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

in Base R

```
data.frame(table(factor(merge(df1,df2)$ID, unique(df1$ID))))
  Var1 Freq
1    1    2
2    2    0
3    3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
inner_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  complete(ID = unique(df1$ID)) %>%
  reframe(Freq = sum(!is.na(date)), .by = "ID")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     ID  Freq
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     0
3     3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with 'dplyr' and 'tidyr':

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF1 %>% 
  semi_join(DF2) %>% 
  count(ID) %>% 
  complete(ID = DF1$ID,
           fill = list(n = 0))

#> Joining with `by = join_by(ID, date)`
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>      ID     n
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     0
#> 3     3     1
```

data

```r
DF1 <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
              date = c("1992-10-15", "2010-02-17", "2019-09-17",
                       "2015-08-18", "2020-10-27", "2020-12-23"))

DF2 <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,1,3,3,3),
              date = c("1992-10-15", "2001-04-25", "2010-02-17",
                       "1990-06-22", "2014-08-18", "2020-10-27"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>